Applying styles to Pandas multiindex, using all index levels for context
I am attempting to style a dataframe with cell colors based on categories provided via the index. Index levels 0 and 1 provide the fruit and part. I want every cell to be colored based on distinct categories of fruit parts.
This works fine when trying to format the cells values throughout the dataframe, but produces issues when trying to style indices.
Below is a sample script to style a sample dataframe of fruit parts.
import pandas as pd

# Dynamically sets style based on index values
def style_row(row):
    color_map = {
        ('apple', 'skin'): 'red',
        ('apple', 'seed'): 'blue',
        ('banana', 'skin'): 'red',
        ('banana', 'seed'): 'blue',
    }
    fruit, part, _ = row.name
    color = color_map.get((fruit, part))
    return [f'background-color: {color}']*len(row)
    
# Sample data
data = [
    ('apple', 'skin', 'color', 'red', 2),
    ('apple', 'skin', 'surface_area', 15, 3),
    ('apple', 'skin', 'texture', 'smooth', 1),
    ('apple', 'seed', 'color', 'grey', 3),
    ('apple', 'seed', 'weight', 4, 2),
    ('banana', 'skin', 'color', 'yellow', 3),
    ('banana', 'skin', 'surface_area', 25, 21),
    ('banana', 'skin', 'texture', 'smooth', 5),
    ('banana', 'seed', 'color', 'grey', 5),
    ('banana', 'seed', 'weight', 6, 2)
]

# Create a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['fruit', 'part', 'property', 'value', 'observances'])
df = df.set_index(['fruit', 'part', 'property'])

# Styled DataFrame
styled_df = df.style.apply(lambda row: style_row(row), axis=1)
styled_df

Result:

That produces a dataframe with red and blue cells, as desired. To finish up, I now only need to style the index level 1 and 2 values, based on the index level 0 and 1 values. This appears to be impossible.
The issue seems to stem from the capabilities of the pandas.io.formats.style.Styler api. Methods such as Styler.map_index, Styler.format_index, and Styler.apply_index each take a callback function in order to style each index value. However, with a multi-index, the callback function is called with values from each index level independently.
This API decision decouples the index values and prevents any callback function from making decisions that depend on more than one index level at the same time.
Docs on map_index, apply_index, and format_index.
Attempt 1 to bypass this issue:
The approach below attempts to enrich each level of the multiindex with context from the other levels, then apply the style, then remove the redundancies previously added to each level of the index.
In theory it should work well, but (for some reason) styled_df.index = new_multiindex produces no effect on the values passed to styled_df.map_index(callback_func). It's as though styled_df.index = new_multiindex does nothing!
# Function to style indices
def style_indices(index_val):
    if isinstance(index_val, tuple):
        fruit, part, _ = index_val
        color_map = {
            ('apple', 'skin'): 'red',
            ('apple', 'seed'): 'blue',
            ('banana', 'skin'): 'red',
            ('banana', 'seed'): 'blue',
        }
        return f'background-color: {color_map.get((fruit, part), "white")}'


# Convert MultiIndex to flat index for modification
flat_index = styled_df.index.to_flat_index()

# Sets index values with more context for callback functions
new_tuples = [(a, flat_index[idx], flat_index[idx]) for idx, (a, b, _) in enumerate(styled_df.index)]
new_multiindex = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(new_tuples)
styled_df.index = new_multiindex # This does not do what you would expect!

# Apply styles to the index
styled_df = styled_df.map_index(lambda index_val: style_indices(index_val), axis=0)

# Revert the index back to its original form
simplified_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(a, b[1], c[2]) for a, b, c in styled_df.index])
styled_df.index = simplified_index # This does not do what you would expect!

styled_df

Notes:

Its important that this dataframe remains multiindexed, so that df.to_excel() automatically applies Merge and Center styling.
The solution must be compatible with the .to_excel() function, so that the Excel file output retains the styles.


Side node, you can't have more than one color in a merged cell (like apple, level0) in Excel.

Thats okay, there will be no need. The fruit column should remain white as we're only trying to style index levels 1 and 2. The decision is based on values from index levels 0 and 1.

You could set_table_styles to color the rows that are not at level 0, based on indices :
st = (
    df.style
    .set_table_styles(
        [
            {
                "selector": ", ".join(map(".row{}:not(.level0)".format, idx)),
                "props": f"background-color: {color_map[pair]}",
            }
            for pair, idx in df.groupby(level=[0, 1]).indices.items()
        ]
    )
)

But if you needed an Excel-friendly approach, one option would be :
css = {
    idx: f"background-color:{color_map[pair]};"
    # you can add more CSS styles to the f-string, if needed..
    for pair, lst in df.groupby(level=[0, 1], sort=False).indices.items()
    for idx in lst
}

st = (
    df.style
    .apply_index(lambda _: pd.Series(css), level=[1, 2])
    .apply(lambda _: pd.Series(css).tolist())
)

